# VBA Excel 2003 Macro independent from specific Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Okay, so I've written a Macro that works fine when launched from the Workbook which I coded it in. However, I need the Macro to be able to work across various Workbooks.

I've moved the Macro to the hidden "personal" workbook, but, now when the code references "ThisWorkBook", well, yeah, it points to the personal workbook.

I had thought of just creating a workbook variable and pointing to the address/name of the workbook... but this varies (the workbook is generated by a system, and the name of the workbook is dependant on the time/date generated).

For reference, I want to put a button on the toolbar in Excel, and when the user clicks it, it runs this Macro. Is there, perhaps, a way to get the name of the Workbook that calls the Macro?

Thanks,
Sam.

Comment: Hi, so now you have 2 workbooks, one is hidden and with the macro (let's name it A),  the other one is visible, let's name it B. 

So you want to call the macro from A in B?

Comment: Hey Larry,

That's exactly it. To give you a bit more background:

We have a system that outputs a spreadsheet full of data (A), and another spreadsheet with a series of formulas in it (B). At the moment, users are having to go through A, copy the right fields, and paste them in B.

I've written a Macro that automates this process, so they now open A, hit the shortcut, and the Macro locates and opens B, then finds the relevant data in A and pastes it over to B.

Comment: Sorry for still being a little bit unclear on the situation and what you want, can we continue the discussion in http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/21244/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-13909747-vba-excel-2003-macro-independent-from?tab=general ?

Comment: Unfortunately, this Macro is currently tied to workbook A... but every week, there's a new A, I need the Macro to be independant from A. I've done this by moving the Macro over to the personal workbook (Workbook C). The problem is that I don't know how to get the Macro to work with A, despite being stored in C. I can't simply create a Workbook variable with the filepath of A coded in, because it can be different everytime. HOWEVER, the Macro is being called by the user launching it in A. Is there a way to get the filename of the Workbook launching the Macro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's a naming convention in workbook A (the data workbook) , you can do the following changes
to identify workbook A

```
Dim wbA As Workbook 'workbook A ( the data workbook) 
Dim wb As Workbook 

For Each wb In Workbooks 'loop through all opened workbooks, matching the name 
    If InStr(wb.Name, "ABC") > 0 Then 
        Set wbA = wb
        Exit For
    End If
Next wb
```

then replace the "ThisWorkBook" by wbA

Answer (score 3):

There are **Active** commands which will allow you to reference the workbook and worksheet that the code is been called from.

```
ActiveCell
ActiveChart
ActiveEncryptionSession
ActivePrinter
ActiveProtectedViewWindow
ActiveSheet
ActiveWindow
ActiveWorkbook
```

All properties of the `Application` object

Answer (score 0):

You could also use VBS instead of a macro. The languages are pretty much identical, and your script would be independent of your workbooks.

As far as identifying which file to use to run the macro (without examples of your data and code, it's hard to be too specific), you can browse for the file you want.

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

Dim strFileName
Dim strFilePath

Dim dPicker
Set dPicker = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a file:", &H4000)

strFilePath = dPicker.self.Path 'will give you the file path of the file you choose,
                                'which you can then use to open/access the file with
                                'the data you need.

'Code

Set dPicker = Nothing
```

If you want to stick with a macro, you can check out the FileDialog Object for using the file picker in VBA.

To get the filename and/or path of an open workbook in VBA, use

```
 ActiveWorkbook.Name
 ActiveWorkbook.Path
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just replace "ThisWorkbook" by "ActiveWorkbook".